# Bulk import products into Woocommerce using WP WC CLI

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, wp-cli

I'm trying to add **1000's** of products into my woocommerce store using wp wc cli via my datasource which will give me the data in the following JSON format:

```
    {
        "name": "Product Name 1",
        "desc": "Desc 1",
        "category": "Main Category",
        "catimageName": "maincategory.jpg",
        "catimageURL": "www.dataserver.com/maincategory.jpg",
        "subcategory": [
          {
            "name": "subcat1",
            "imageName": "subcat1.jpg",
            "imageURL": "www.dataserver.com/subcat1.jpg"
          },
          {
            "name": "subcat2",
            "imageName": "subcat2.jpg",
            "imageURL": "www.dataserver.com/subcat2.jpg"
          },
          {
            "name": "subcat3",
            "imageName": "subcat3.jpg",
            "imageURL": "www.dataserver.com/subcat3.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "attributes": [
          {
            "SKU": "PP1001",
            "Height": 50,
            "Weight": 50
          }
        ],
        "prodimageName": "prod1.jpg",
        "prodimageURL": "www.dataserver.com/prod1.jpg"
      },
      {
        "name": "Product Name 2",
        "desc": "Desc 2",
        "category": "Main Category 2",
        "catimageName": "maincat2.jpg",
        "catimageURL": "www.dataserver.com/maincat2.jpg",
        "subcategory": [
          {
            "name": "subcat1",
            "imageName": "subcat1.jpg",
            "imageURL": "www.dataserver.com/subcat1.jpg"
          },
          {
            "name": "subcat2",
            "imageName": "subcat2.jpg",
            "imageURL": "www.dataserver.com/subcat2.jpg"
          },
          {
            "name": "subcat3",
            "imageName": "subcat3.jpg",
            "imageURL": "www.dataserver.com/subcat3.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "attributes": [
          {
            "SKU": "PP1002",
            "Height": 50,
            "Weight": 50
          }
        ],
        "prodimageName": "prod2.jpg",
        "prodimageURL": "www.dataserver.com/prod2.jpg"
      },
{
        "name": "Product Name 3",
        "desc": "Desc 3",
        "category": "Main Category 1",
        "catimageName": "maincat1.jpg",
        "catimageURL": "www.dataserver.com/maincat1.jpg",
        "subcategory": [
          {
            "name": "subcat1",
            "imageName": "subcat1.jpg",
            "imageURL": "www.dataserver.com/subcat1.jpg"
          },
          {
            "name": "subcat2",
            "imageName": "subcat2.jpg",
            "imageURL": "www.dataserver.com/subcat2.jpg"
          },
          {
            "name": "subcat3",
            "imageName": "subcat3.jpg",
            "imageURL": "www.dataserver.com/subcat3.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "attributes": [
          {
            "SKU": "PP1002",
            "Height": 50,
            "Weight": 50
          }
        ],
        "prodimageName": "prod3.jpg",
        "prodimageURL": "www.dataserver.com/prod3.jpg"
      },
```

**My question is what is the best way to achieve this?**

As per my research the Woocommerce REST API and wp wc cli pose too many challanges (categories , sub categories can only be used as ID's and not the actual text, so I have to insert the product categories and sub-categories, store their id trail and then link it back to the proper products).

[wooCommerce Rest API - Add Product](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product)

[WP WC CLI Create Product](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/WC-CLI-Commands#wc-product-create)

[WP WC CLI FAQ Regarding Category Text](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/WC-CLI-Overview#frequently-asked-questions)

I have also checked the Woocommerce CSV Export/Import. It works fine for my usecase but I need to do the same through my command line or programatically.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated! TIA!

P.S - Woocommerce doesn't have a command line functionality for CSV Import

[Wordpress Woocommerce Support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/run-wc-csv-product-importer-from-wp-cli/)

[Github response of Woocommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/21624#issuecomment-431950199)

Answer (score 2):

Did some digging it looks like this can be done through a bash script through
wp-cli via the wp wc product create command and then running it through the read -r command
see the link below for more details
https://remicorson.com/bulk-import-woocommerce-products-with-wp-cli-the-and-alfred/
for the .csv file it may be better to create a python script to deal with the logic/columns of the csv file through a libary to make products easier to import and then adjust the params for the product create command as needed via something like sys argv

hope this helps